# How does moshi access Private fields?

Tags: java, android, moshi

I am having following model class:

```
class Recipe {

  @Json(name = "name") private String mName;

  public String getName() {
    return mName;
  }
}
```

and I am parsing Json using following code:

```
private static final JsonAdapter<List<Recipe>> recipeListAdapter = moshi.adapter(
      Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Recipe.class));

Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(URL)
          .build();
      try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
          throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }
        return recipeListAdapter.fromJson(response.body().source());
      }
    })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.
        .subscribe(recipes -> {
          Log.i(TAG, recipes.get(0).getName() + "");
        }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

So here I am able to set private field even if it is private and there is no setter either.

How is this possible?
How is moshi able to set private field?

Comment: Using the magical feature of java called "reflection".  Try a google search for "how to set private member java" for much details.

Comment: Specifically, with Field.setAccessible. Take a look at the implementation of ClassJsonAdapter.
https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/f53a77d311879f509b202ee5ea994301985a30d9/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/ClassJsonAdapter.java#L94